# What is the Bigquery Date syntax to call "Previous Month" and "Current Month" in yyyymmdd format dynamically?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to call "Previous Month" and "Current Month" in yyyymmdd format dynamically without mentioning explicitly in the query as mentioned below

WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '2022[PREVIOUSMONTH]01' AND '2022[CURRENTMONTH]07' in in yyyymmdd format

WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20220201' AND '20220307' in yyyymmdd format

In the below query, how to call [PREVIOUSMONTH] AND [CURRENTMONTH]in yyyymmdd format dynamically without mentioning explicitly in the query '20220201' AND '20220307'

```
select 
stream_id,app_info.id,app_info.version,  
event_date,event_name, 
  param1.value.string_value as category,
  param2.value.string_value as action,
  param3.value.string_value as label,
  count(1) as totalevent,count( distinct user_pseudo_id ) as uniqueusers
From `abc_150838411.events_*`,
UNNEST(event_params) as param1,
UNNEST(event_params) as param2,
UNNEST(event_params) as param3
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20220201' AND '20220307'
and param1.key='category' 
and param2.key='action' 
and param3.key='label' 
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8
order by totalevent desc
```

Pls Note:

Month Syntax needs to be populated in in yyyymmdd format

WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20220201' AND '20220307'

WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '2022[PopulatePreviousMonthUsingMonthSyntax]01' AND '2022[PopulateCurrnetMonthSyntax]07'

Pls. Help Thanks

Comment: Hello! You can check my answer. Let me know if it addresses your requirement.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the month changes dynamically? Are you trying to retrieve multiple sets of data? For example, 1st set: `20220201` to `20220307`, 2nd set: `20220101` to `20220207` and so on.

Comment: I want 1st set: 20220201 to 20220307 result only, not the 2nd Set

Comment: What is the basis for this dynamic change in the month component? Can you also explain your use case or what you are trying to achieve with this query?

Comment: Hi @RamakrishnanM. Good to know that the answer helped! Can you accept the answer since it addressed your issue?

Comment: Accepted Kabilan

Comment: @Kabilan Requesting your Help for the Below Query
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71586414/how-to-fetch-avg-time-on-screen-from-firebase-bigquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, consider the below query where the `date` and `year` are hardcoded and the `month` is dynamic. I have tested the query and it gives the results within the provided time frame. The query is based on @Mikhail's answer and your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71409195/what-is-the-bigquery-date-syntax-to-call-previous-month-and-current-month-in#comment126238031_71417146).

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.ga4_obfuscated_sample_ecommerce.events_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("2022%m07", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
  AND
  FORMAT_DATE("2022%m01", CURRENT_DATE())
LIMIT
  10;
```

Comment: Thanks Kabilan Mohanraj  You nailed the problem. Awesome... Thank you so Much

Answer (score 1):

You want to:

- change the formatting of the date = `FORMAT_DATE`
- of the current month = truncating `DATE_TRUNC` the `MONTH` of the `CURRENT_DATE`,
- or of the previous month = same but truncating the `MONTH` of the `CURRENT_DATE` 1 month ago:

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(),MONTH)) AS current_month,
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d",DATE_TRUNC( DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH),MONTH)) AS previous_month
```

this gives:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Clidby for the support. Requesting your support the below. 

Month Syntax needs to be populated in in yyyymmdd format

WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20220201' AND '20220307'

WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '2022[PopulatePreviousMonthUsingMonthSyntax]01' AND '2022[PopulateCurrnetMonthSyntax]07'

Pls. Help Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider shortcut approach

```
SELECT
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m01", CURRENT_DATE()) AS current_month,
  FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m01", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS previous_month
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for the support. I want to change only the <Month> Component <dynamically>, but the <year> and <date> remains <static> in yyyymmdd format WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20220201' AND '20220307' * yyyy is <Static Component> Static Value is 2022 (Year static value is provided manually in the query) * mm is <Dynamic Component> Dynamic Value 02 or 03 that is (Previous Month) or (Current Month) needs to be populated dynamically in the query * dd is <Static Component> Static Value is is 01 or 07 (Date static value is provided manually in the query). Pls. Help. Thanks

Comment: Mikhail: Humbly Requesting your help. Pls. Respond.

Comment: I thought I answered your question  - but with your above comments - it is really not clear what you actually want to achieve :o(

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for the Response. Updated the Pls Note Content in the Query for better Clarity.  Pls. Help

Comment: Pls Note:

Month Syntax needs to be populated in in yyyymmdd format

WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20220201' AND '20220307'

WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '2022[PopulatePreviousMonthUsingMonthSyntax]01' AND '2022[PopulateCurrnetMonthSyntax]07'

Pls. Help Thanks